# Android - HTML5 custom LAUNCHER

Tags: android, html, launcher

I want to create my custom android launcher but not with java code. I want to create it with HTML5 code. I've seen some launchers with HTML5 but not the documentation. Does anyone can give me some links or some tutorials/documentation to start? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone can give me some links or some tutorials/documentation to start?

You could define much of the UI as HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Via PhoneGap, you could deploy this as an app. However, you will still need Java code -- or perhaps a PhoneGap plugin, if someone has written one -- to be able to access information about the installed apps, in order to populate your launcher.